# What the correct way to exit an Express app.all

Tags: javascript, express

This is my `app.all`. Basically, I'm calling a `fetchBuildings` function based on the building ID/Hash, then setting `title`, `description`, and `image` based on the response:

```
app.all('/:id', function (req, res) {
  const hash = req.params.id
  const obj = {}
  if (hash === 'undefined') {
    obj.title = 'iStaging LiveTour'
    obj.description = ''
    obj.image = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexcheninfo/vue-tmux-example/master/app/istaging.jpg'
    return
  }
  fetchBuildingsByHash(hash).then(({title, description, image, isBasicPlan}) => {
    if (isBasicPlan) {
      obj.title = 'iStaging LiveTour'
      obj.description = ''
      obj.image = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexcheninfo/vue-tmux-example/master/app/istaging.jpg'
    } else {
      obj.title = title || 'iStaging LiveTour'
      obj.description = description || ''
      obj.image = image || 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexcheninfo/vue-tmux-example/master/app/istaging.jpg'
    }
    res.render('index.ejs', obj)
  }).catch((err) => {
    const obj = {
      title: 'notFound'
    }
    res.render('404.ejs', obj)
  })
});
```

Sometimes `hash` is `'undefined'` so I want to stop the code when that happens.

I'm just using `return` here, but I wonder if this is the conventional way of doing it. Is there another more 'proper' way?

Comment: You can have `else` block as well after `if` block..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always either return a response, or pass the request along the middleware chain. If you just return, the request will get "stuck": the client will keep on waiting for a response that never comes, and eventually it will time out.

Let's assume that passing an hash of `undefined` is considered invalid. You could return a 400 (*"Bad Request"*) response in that case:

```
if (hash === 'undefined') {
  return res.sendStatus(400);
}
```

If you want to pass the request along, which will likely result in a 404 (*"Not Found"*) response being returned by Express:

```
app.all('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  const hash = req.params.id
  const obj = {}
  if (hash === 'undefined') {
    return next();
  }
  ...
})
```

Or explicitly pass an error, resulting in a 500 (*"Internal Server Error"*) response returned by Express:

```
if (hash === 'undefined') {
  return next(Error('invalid hash'));
}
```

Comment: All the options that you suggested do the same thing. The code stops but nothing is output.

Comment: I thought your question was how to properly "exit" an Express request, which is what I was answering to :)